How to authenticate resource owner with JWT token on Spring Authorization Server for requests to /oauth2/authorize?
I'm migrating from spring-boot 2.7.18 to 3.3.3 and moving from
spring-security-oauth2 to spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server
UPDATE:
My usecase:
I have gateway service which is sitting between outside world and private network. This gateway existed before authorization server and it's part of system architecture. Basically it intercepts every request under for example https://example.com domain, now when my public clients call https://example.com/oauth2/authorize gateway service will intercept request, it will figure out that user doesn't have active session and then it will redirect user to login page hosted on domain which is not the same as domain for oauth2 server. After user logs in successfully gateway service will redirect to initially requested url https://example.com/oauth2/authorize and will add Bearer token to request headers.
Next on my oauth2 server I need to validate JWT Bearer token and if it's valid let the authorization library to execute next thing Provider/filter in the chain.
my oauth2-server had this defaultSecurityFilterChain config
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/oauth/authorize")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter(secret), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomHSTSFilter(), CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter.class)

which worked fine with old spring-security-oauth2 library
Now since a lot of things changed in the new spring security and oauth2-authorization-server I have changed defaultSecurityFilterChain config to this
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                         .requestMatchers("/oauth2/authorize","/hello").authenticated())
                .addFilterAfter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter(secret), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new CustomHSTSFilter(), CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

Unfortunately this doesn't work, and I would appreciate if someone can explain how should I configure security filter chain to work.
My /hello endpoint which I defined is working fine, but when I send request to GET /oauth2/authorize?client_id=.... I get 403 Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
I can see im my logs that my CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter is invoked and GET /oauth2/authorize?client_id=.... gets secured BUT then it tries to secure GET  /error?client_id=... and it fails  in AuthorizationFilter I get Access Denied with message Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access.
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong in my config, and am I missing?
I have tried to add .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll() in my defaultSecurityFilterChain then /error gets Secured but I get 404 without any message.
I have also tried to add .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll() with same 404 result
Also I have tried changing my authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain with adding custom authorizationRequestConverter on authorizationEndpoint but I found myself writing more complex code than it should be and figured out that this is probably not a way to implement this.

I also have a requirement to authenticate requests to the /oauth2/authorize endpoint by a bearer token.  I changed my authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain with adding a custom authorizationRequestConverter on authorizationEndpoint.  My custom AuthenticationConverter class has around 35 lines of code.  How much complex code do you consider to be too much?

why have you written some strange custom filters? spring security has full support for oauth2 so why are you not using the built in features of spring security?

Hi @ChinHuang, thanks for your response. I created a custom JwtAuthenticationToken that extends AbstractAuthenticationToken and implemented authorizationRequestConverter to return it. This caused an error as AuthenticationProvider couldn’t cast JwtAuthenticationToken to OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken. After reviewing the implementation of OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter, I found it too complex to override.
Would it be possible for you to share how you implemented your custom authorizationRequestConverter?

Hi @Toerktumlare, thanks for your response. Maybe I missed important information from spring-security and spring authorization server documentation, but I couldn't find a proper way to authenticate resource owner with JWT Bearer token. That is why I tried with custom  Filters and as I mentioned my oauth2 server used custom filters before with old spring boot and deprecated spring-security-oauth2 library.
I would appreciate if you have constructive solution to propose.

i do not really understand why you are building home made security that does not follow the specification, you are only making everything so much harder for yourself. Your question is also very unclear. When you are saying "users", what are you actually meaning? Because you first say "user", then you say "resource owner". Oauth2 has no concept of resource owners, and users are end users using a webpage. And you also do not authenticate someone with a token. You authorize someone with a token, they have already authenticated if they are in possession of a token.

I've updated my question to be more clear. How do you mean that Oauth2 has no concept of resource owners? According to the RFC  spec (see Section 1.1: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-16#section-1.1), the resource owner is a key concept and refers to the end user. I'm not trying to build a custom security solution; I just need to handle this step where the authorization server authenticates the resource owner via a JWT token. This needs to happen before the resource owner can grant the client permission to access resources on their behalf.

This question is similar to: Spring Authorization Server: How to use login form hosted on a separate application?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @SteveRiesenberg thank you for the response. I have read your answer on other similar question. Unfortunately it's not same as my use case. I have also updated my question and hopefully it's clear now.

This use case is in fact the same as the one stated in the question I linked to, where I note that it is not the best way to do things. But you have not stated why you need to do it this way. You say it's different because of a gateway, but it seems you introduced the gateway as part of the solution. IMO the solution you have introduced here is an anti-pattern because you are using the JWT as a session token to the authorization server. Instead, the auth server should be connected to the 3rd party authentication system using OAuth2 and have its own session.

Hi @SteveRiesenberg I have update my question again to indicate that gateway existed before and it's part of system architecture, I have to stick with it and it's JWT tokens.
Reading your answer on other AS question, you provided example that includes authentication entry point. In my case gateway intercepts every request and that means user will always reach AS as authenticated user. If I apply that solution I would redirect already authenticated user to external SSO via authentication entry point.

Section 3.1 of the OAuth 2 specification requires for the authorization endpoint:

The authorization server MUST first authenticate the resource owner. The way in which the authorization server authenticates the resource owner (e.g., username and password login, passkey, federated login, or by using an established session) is beyond the scope of this specification.

The example in the Spring Authorization Server documentation redirects to a login form to submit a username and password, but you want to authenticate by a bearer token instead.  The Spring Authorization Server developers suggest you can configure a custom AuthenticationConverter in the authorizationRequestConverter of the authorizationEndpoint:
http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
    .authorizationEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint
        .authorizationRequestConverter(customAuthorizationRequestConverter))

The custom AuthenticationConverter verifies the bearer token and gets the principal from the bearer token:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestConverter implements AuthenticationConverter {

  private static final OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter DELEGATE =
      new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter();
  private static final DefaultBearerTokenResolver BEARER_TOKEN_RESOLVER =
      new DefaultBearerTokenResolver();
  private static final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter GRANTED_AUTHORITIES_CONVERTER =
      new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();

  private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

  private Jwt getJwt(String encoded) {
    try {
      return jwtDecoder.decode(encoded);
    } catch (JwtException e) {
      throw new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationException(
          new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_TOKEN, e.getMessage(), null), e, null);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication convert(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String accessTokenValue = BEARER_TOKEN_RESOLVER.resolve(request);
    if (accessTokenValue == null) {
      return null;
    }

    var authentication = (OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken) DELEGATE.convert(request);
    if (authentication == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Jwt jwt = getJwt(accessTokenValue);
    String username = jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB);
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = GRANTED_AUTHORITIES_CONVERTER.convert(jwt);
    var principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);

    return new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken(
        authentication.getAuthorizationUri(),
        authentication.getClientId(),
        principal,
        authentication.getRedirectUri(),
        authentication.getState(),
        authentication.getScopes(),
        authentication.getAdditionalParameters());
  }
}


Hi @ChinHuang, thank you very much, with this I am able to authenticated resource owner via JWT token.
I made a mistake with returning Authentication from my custom Authorization request converter.

Authentication converters are not intended to set the SecurityContextHolder. I don't think this would be a recommended solution to this problem.

You are correct.  I edited my answer to not set the SecurityContextHolder.

I would still not recommend this approach. You are treating the JWT as a session token to the auth server, when you could instead connect the auth server to the 3rd party authentication system using OAuth2 and have a normal session in the auth server. Also, you could avoid writing the JWT validation code by using http.oauth2ResourceServer() in the auth server filter chain which would be safer (though I still don't recommend it).
